# Error while trying to start another composer business network

Tags: hyperledger-composer

I am using pc with Ubuntu 16.0.4LTS x64 installed on it. i have two different business models created in hyperledger composer. When i install and start the first business network, it doesn't produce any errors. But when try to start second business network after it has been installed. It produces following error.

```
✖ Starting business network definition. This may take a minute...
Error: Error trying to start business network. Error: No valid responses from any peers.
Response from attempted peer comms was an error: Error: REQUEST_TIMEOUT
Command failed
```

If i again execute composer network start with the same business, it produces following error

```
✖ Starting business network definition. This may take a minute...
Error: Error trying to start business network. Error: No valid responses from any peers.
Response from attempted peer comms was an error: Error: 2 UNKNOWN: premature execution - chaincode (tutorial-network:0.0.2-deploy.28) is being launched
Command failed
```

I have made following change in **docker-compose.yml**.

```
- CORE_CHAINCODE_STARTUPTIMEOUT=1200s
```

But it still produces same error if i try to install and then start again after stopping and tearing down the previous network.

I have looked into same issue here

[https://github.com/hyperledger/composer/issues/3731](http://composer%20network%20start%20is%20not%20working%20v%200.19%20#3731)

There is another solution given that is using npmrc file and passing it in arguments but i am having trouble understanding how to make npmrc file and what should be its contents.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I faced the same issue a while back. I added two environmental variables in the docker-compose file, `- CORE_CHAINCODE_STARTUPTIMEOUT=900s,- CORE_CHAINCODE_EXECUTETIMEOUT=1200s` for all the peers. According to the network speed and computing power you have, startuptime and executetime will vary. Try to tune them if you are still getting timeout.

Comment: Also tear down the whole network and remove dev-peer docker images generated.

Comment: Thanks , adding - CORE_CHAINCODE_EXECUTETIMEOUT=1200s, worked

Answer (score 0):

If you are not getting any npm errors in the Peer logs then you don't need to worry about the npmrc file.  Check the peer log with this command if you are using the standard developer fabric from the Composer docs - `docker logs peer0.org1.example.com`

In addition to setting the environment variables suggested by Apoorv Chandurkar I would also suggest modifying timeout in the connection.json for your PeerAdmin card.  You will see 4 timeouts (3 for the Peer and 1 for the Order) that are set for 300 seconds - I would increase those to 1200 seconds too.  The connection.json file will be in a folder like: `~/.composer/cards/PeerAdmin@hlfv1/connection.json`

Comment: You were right, there were no logs about npm error but about network connectivity. But for future reference can you guide me on how to make such a file i.e. npmrc if problem regrading npm occurs during composer network start. Thanks